# Sqlite in Unity

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, unity-game-engine

Here's my code working fine. Only problem I'm facing is that when I'm logged in it won't load my level. Here's my code.

```
public void Loginfunc()
{
    string usernameforsignin = UsernameSignin.text;
    string passwordforsingin = PasswordSignin.text;

    if (usernameforsignin == "sdsefa" || passwordforsingin == "sefse") {
        //think what to do here like prompt a form or something
        ShowFullName.text="Love";
    } 
    else {

        string sqlitequery = "SELECT FullName,Wins,Loss FROM `Player` WHERE           Username='{0}' AND Password ='{1}'";
        sqlitequery = string.Format (sqlitequery, usernameforsignin,  passwordforsingin);

        string conn = "Data  Source=C://Users//Usman//Desktop//GameProject10.07//Assets//DatabaseLove"; 

        IDbConnection dbconn;

        dbconn = (IDbConnection) new SqliteConnection(conn);
        dbconn.Open();          
        IDbCommand dbcmd = dbconn.CreateCommand();
        dbcmd.CommandText = sqlitequery;
        IDataReader reader = dbcmd.ExecuteReader();

        if(reader.Read() == true)
        {
            isSignin=true;

            SignInCanvas.enabled=false;
            MainMenuCanvas.enabled=true;
            ShowFullName.text= reader.GetString(0); 
            TotalWinsData.text = reader.GetInt16(1).ToString();
            TotalLossedData.text = reader.GetInt16(2).ToString();
            PlayerStats.enabled=true;


        }
        else
        {

            TotalWinsData.text="MAera ";
        }

        reader.Close();

        dbconn.Close();


    }

}
```

When I'm logedIn I click on the `Start` Button.Coding of start buttons is.

```
public void StartGame()
{
    ShowFullName.text= "I'm there";

   Application.LoadLevel (1);

}
```

It shows the `ShowFullName` value but gets stuck on the `Apllication.laodlevel (1);`.
What should I do?
Before the login game starts without any problem what should I do now?

Comment: Did you add your level to the build settings? (`File -> Build Settings... -> Add current`). Does it just hang when you load the scene?

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt yes bro i have added. Beofre logginh in it works fine fter log in it wont work with no error.

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt yes it hangs.

Comment: Your last post was completely against rules of this site as well as general ethics. Try to pull that off again, and you'll likely be booted from this site.